# How to move all files in a directory that have a specific prefix?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I'm creating an `sh` script file to move files from a folder to another, but only move files starting with `system@`.

So how can I move only the files that start with `system@`?

```
#pseudo-code
foreach file "system@*.*" in dir
move to /.../...
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should really look at a bash reference before you post a question like this.

```
for file in dir/system@*; do 
    mv "$file" /path/to/destination
done
```

Apparently I'm more tired than I thought. [3coins' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701044/how-to-move-all-files-in-a-directory-that-have-a-specific-prefix/12701071#comment17147314_12701044) is even better:

```
mv dir/system@* /path/to/destination
```

Assuming you don't have enough matching files to exceed the maximum command line length.

Comment: imo the one liner was much easier